# MySQL has mysqlslap schema but "1049 Unknown database 'mysqlslap'" error persists

Tags: mysql, ldap

I'm executing the below command

```sh
mysqlslap -uroot -pmypassword --query="show databases;" --delimiter=";" --verbose -P3307 --host=machine01 --create-schema=mysqlslap
```

But it keeps returning this error

> mysqlslap: Error when connecting to server: 1049 Unknown database 'schema'

**Note:** I also have the schema *mysqlslap* explicitly created in my instance.

Comment: Can you refer this? [https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-measure-mysql-query-performance-with-mysqlslap]

Comment: @jarlh How is this not about [tag:sql]?

Comment: @user207421, no SQL above. And I doubt the answer will include any.